# nextjs Router.back does a full page refresh

Tags: javascript, react-router, next.js

I have a page: `pages/conversations/[id].tsx`, which has:

```
import Router, { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function ConversationPage() {
    const router = useRouter()
    ...
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, bottom: 0 }}>
            <Appbar.Header style={{ zIndex: 10, elevation: 10}}>
                <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => router.back()} />
                <Appbar.Content
                    title={' '}
                />
   ...
```

When I click that, it reloads the entire page and wipes out the state information. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful in finding asolution.

NextJS `router.back()` only calls the native `window.history.back()`

Here is the source code https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerback

Maybe you should use `router.push()` indirectly to go back using the `as` param?

```
<span onClick={() => Router.push('/post/[pid]', '/post/abc')}>
      Click me
</span>
```

Here is the documentation

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#linking-between-pages
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage

> When linking to a route with dynamic path segments you have to provide
> `href` and `as` to make sure the router knows which JavaScript file to
> load.

Comment: How can I track the previous URL then? It would be a search URL with various `query` params

Comment: Maybe you can pass the search url as a prop to the component?

Comment: How would I do that? When I got this component, you're saying I should pass a query param of the previous URL?

Comment: you can use the req header in getIntialProps or getServerSideProps. Here is a req header having the referer as sample from one my next JS project. headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36',
    accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
    
    referer: 'http://localhost:3000/questions',

Comment: Added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To track the previous url, you can use the referer field in req.headers from the req object in getIntialProps or getServerSideProps.

Sample header response in nextjs getInitialProps

```
headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36',
    accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    referer: 'http://localhost:3000/questions',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    cookie: '_ga=GA1.1.20509028897'
  },
```